# Change JS script in Unity so it changes scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have JavaScript code that I'm using and it makes a pause menu in my Unity game. It is a simple pause menu that shows a "*Main Menu*" and "*Quit Game*" button.

How would I bind a button to scenes in Unity? So If I hit "*Main Menu*" I want it to take me to `scene1`, and replace the "*Quit Game*" button with a music button to turn my music on/off.

Comment: what UI system are you using, NGUI, uGUI?

Comment: `Application.LoadLevel("levelName")` loads a new scene.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pause menu script:

```
#pragma strict
var musicBtnText : String = "Music: On";
var musicOn : boolean = true;
var isPaused : boolean = false;


function Update()
{
    if(musicOn)
    {
        musicBtnText = "Music: On";
    }
    else
    {
        musicBtnText = "Music: Off";
    }
    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
    {
        isPaused = !isPaused;
        if(isPaused)
        {
             Time.timeScale = 0;
        }
        else
        {
             Time.timeScale = 1;
        }
    }
}

function OnGUI()
{
    if(isPaused)
    {
        if (GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-50, 240, 100, 40), "Main Menu"))
        {
            Application.LoadLevel("scene1");
        }
        if(GUI.Button(Rect(Screen.width/2-50, 300, 100, 40), "" + musicBtnText))
        {
            musicOn = !musicOn;
            GameObject.Find("cameraName").GetComponent(AudioListener).enabled = !GameObject.Find("cameraName").GetComponent(AudioListener).enabled;
        }
    }
}
```

However if you want to implement this into your own code, one thing to note is that when making buttons in unity, you contain them in an if statement. That way whatever code that is inside the if statement is called upon clicking that button. As for turning music on and off, you would want to enable and disable the main audio listener, which by default is attached to the main camera. So in my code when it says `GameObject.Find("cameraName")` replace camera name with the name of your main camera. Lastly, loading levels in unity is done by calling `Application.LoadLevel("levelName")`. Best of luck! Comment if this gives you any errors and I'd be glad to help.
**In C#:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour {

    public string musicBtnText = "Music: On";
    public bool musicOn = true;
    public bool isPaused = false;


    void Update()
    {
        if(musicOn)
        {
            musicBtnText = "Music: On";
        }
        else
        {
            musicBtnText = "Music: Off";
        }
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            isPaused = !isPaused;
            if(isPaused)
            {
                 Time.timeScale = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                 Time.timeScale = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    void OnGUI()
    {
        if(isPaused)
        {
            if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50, 240, 100, 40), "Main Menu"))
            {
                Application.LoadLevel("scene1");
            }
            if(GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width/2-50, 300, 100, 40), "" + musicBtnText))
            {
                musicOn = !musicOn;
                GameObject.Find("cameraName").GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled = !GameObject.Find("cameraName").GetComponent<AudioListener>().enabled;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good, only problem is this: Assets/Pause Menu/PauseMenu.js(2,20): BCE0018: The name 'string' does not denote a valid type ('not found'). Did you mean 'UnityEngine.Networking.NetworkSystem.StringMessage'?

Comment: Thank you so much, Works great! Since you seem to know a lot about this, have you ever added mobile controls to a Unity game? And how did you do it? Now when I test the game on my Android tablet the buttons work, but I can't control the car. Is there a way to control a player WITHOUT changing the default physics (carcontroller.cs in the unity standard assets). Big thanks!

Comment: Hm let me look into this, however I notice one thing in there that doesnt look you good. You are talking about a script that has a .cs extension (c# file), however this pause script is in javascript. The languages cannot be used interchangeably in the same project, pick one and stick with it. If you want to use c# though I can convert this script to c# for you

Comment: How can I convert JavaScript to C#? Do I need to do this manually or is there a program for this? Thanks!

Comment: There are some programs for this, however they don't always work so you'd want to know the language you're converting to in order to fix the mistakes the program makes

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately when I press P the game stops, and when I press P again the game just freezes. In other words, the P key simply freezes the whole game, and my car stops moving and I can't get it to move again. IMO you might be missing something to tell Unity to start moving the car again. Also, is there a way I can change "P" to an on-screen button. I need it onscreen for mobile devices without keyboards. Thank you! BTW I'm learning a bit of coding here looking at what you write so I won't be asking you for code forever :)